# How to substitute the first line and split the first string on the following line:

Tags: bash, scripting

I am just new to scripting and I need some help. I have something like a bazillion files that look like this.

> Assign F2  Height
>
> 3IleN  2.34025e+07
>
> 4PheN  2.05028e+07
>
> 6LysN  1.43672e+07
>
> 7ThrN  1.49120e+07
>
> 8LeuN  1.30838e+07
>
> 9ThrN  1.44298e+07

And i want it to look like this + save it in another file with the same name as the previous file however, with a "MOD" written at the beginning.

> Number AA  Height
>
> 3 IleN    6.20756e+07
>
> 4 PheN    5.26499e+07
>
> 7 ThrN    3.00216e+07
>
> 8 LeuN    3.26377e+07
>
> 9 ThrN    4.03901e+07
>
> 10    GlyN    2.73659e+07
>
> 12    ThrN    3.16319e+07
>
> 13    IleN    5.94604e+07

If you could please describe and explain the parameters used, that would be of great help.

Thanks!

Comment: The numbers in this make no sense.  In the first example, you have a file named `3IleN 2.34025e+07`, and in the second there is a file named `3 IleN 6.20756e+07`.  I see the space after the `3`, however, the numbers in the two don't match up whatsoever.

Also, where the heck did `Number AA Height` come from?  Is that just a new header you want?

Comment: Yes Tim, it is a new Header. and the numbers do not really matter, i just used to different files. All i want is to split the number on the first string from the characters. from 3Ile to 3 Ile. 

Sorry, i could have been more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)/\1 /' filename
```